# get attribute and use it to find dom

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get an 'href' attribute and to get the properties of a dom element with the same id. I'm confusing string and objects and need some help.

here the code:

```
    $('a').not('external_link').click(function(){

            var myString = $(this).attr('href');
            var myObject = $(('\'') + myId + ('\''));
            var position = myObject.position();
```

so, basically what I'm trying to do is just get href="#work" and have div#work.properties, that's it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your `.not('')` is wrong; you need a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').not('external_link').click(function(){

        var myId = $(this).attr('href');
        var myObject = $(myId);
        var position = myObject.position();
```

I think this is more what you are looking for

Comment: this works fine, I have to be sure of classes names before posting my headaches. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors are ordinary strings; they aren't strings that contain `'` characters.

You can write `$(myId)`